# How to clean up directory structure from botched rsync operation?

Tags: bash, directory, rsync

In a bash script, I am rsync'ing many directories. However, in my script I forgot to put a trailing slash at the end of the source directory.  As a result, I have something like

```
rsync /first/path/dir /second/path/dir
```

in my script, which I know is wrong, and ends up creating

```
/second/path/dir/dir
```

in the destination directory, which is not what I want at all.

Is there a quick way I can use the find command to find all instances of "dir/dir" and perform an 'rm -rf' without losing the other original contents of /second/path/dir ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the -path argument to unix find command to locate (and remove) 'dir/dir'

```
find . -path \*/dir/dir -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "dir/dir" is different for each directory. I was hoping for a regex to automatically detect paths where the last two directories in the path are the same.

Comment: you can use the -regex argument as follows.

    find . -regex ".*/\([^\/]+\)/\1" -exec rm -rf {} \;